# App crashes on setContent(new Intent ) in tabhost

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, tabs, android-tabhost

I'm using Android's Tabhost and can't view my A activity in Main Activity. 
It throws error in `setIndicatorsetContent(new Intent(this, a.class))`. What changes are required? Do I need to change some code in A activity?

MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    //tab 1
    TabHost.TabSpec spec  = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
    spec.setContent(new Intent(this,a.class));
    spec.setIndicator("Exams");
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //tab 2
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    spec.setContent(new Intent(this,b.class));
    spec.setIndicator("Pratice");
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    }
}
```

Error Log

```
Process: com.example.vivek.helloworld, PID: 17776
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vivek.helloworld/com.example.vivek.helloworld.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:722)
    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:388)
    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:222)
    at com.example.vivek.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
```

Comment: Please share you error log...

Comment: It says to add LocalActivityManager but don't know where to add this activity or child "a activity" ?

Comment: "Learning Android Tabhost" – Yeah, don't do that. That's an old, outdated component, and the particular way you're trying to use it has been deprecated for many years, since API level 13. Instead, use `Fragment`s in a single `Activity`, and `TabLayout`, with a `ViewPager`, if you like. Android Studio offers a template that'll set up most of that for you.

Comment: @VivekGautam Hi Vivek, has my answer assisted you in fixing this error?

Answer (score 0):

As it's stated within the error: 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?`

Your need to state the localactivitymanager in order to resolve this error. (FYI - IllegalStateException occurs when you've invoked the method at an illegal or inappropriate time)
Therefore, you need to inform the activity about the state and in order to do so, implement the following code:

```
tabHost.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());
```

I also want to bring to your attention that TabHost has been deprecated since API Level 13. The replacement for TabHost is Fragment and Fragment Manager. It's good practice to ensure you are not implementing outdated/deprecated classes.

> This class was deprecated in API level 13.
>   Use the new Fragment and FragmentManager APIs instead; these are also
>   available on older platforms through the Android compatibility
>   package.

[LocalActivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LocalActivityManager)

Comment: Please take some time to read [answer] and provide some extra information regarding your answer and how it solves the original question. Short answers like this are not helpful and may be deleted.

Comment: @SimplyGed +1 agreed. I wasn't totally sure about the answer and wanted to determine if it fixed the initial problem. Regardless, I'll be adding additional information as recommended.

Comment: Great. Sometimes it is better to add suggestions as a comment and if the OP confirms it solves the problem you can add it as an answer.